# Why does function taking ownership of i32 need it to be mutable?

Tags: rust

I have a simple algorithm for calculating the greatest common divisor of two numbers using Euclid's algorithm. As you can see the function takes ownership of two i32s and returns an i32. My understanding of the borrow checker is that as i32 implements copy this code should be fine. However, the compiler is telling me I need to state the variables are mutable.

```rust
fn euclid_gcd(a: i32, b: i32)  -> i32 {
    while a != b {
        if a > b {
            a = a - b
        }
        else {
            b = b - a
        }
    }

    a
}
```

`-->`

```
fn euclid_gcd(mut a: i32, mut b: i32)  -> i32 {
```

I have made the suggested change and the code works fine but I still don't understand why it was necessary. Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: `i32` is the type of a value, and `a` is the owner of `i32` typed values. If you want to modify the values  that `a` holds then  it needs to be mutable

Comment: For the: _My understanding of the borrow checker is that as i32 implements clone this code should be fine_ `Clone` has no effect on borrow checker directly, maybe you meant `Copy`? `Copy` means if it's implemented Rust will copy the value for target owner instead of moving.

Comment: @ÖmerErden, yes I did. I'm relatively new to rust and I keep getting those mixed up. I'll edit the question to fix it.

Comment: Some people don't like to write `mut` bindings in the function definition, because it looks like it affects the signature of the function, but it does not. That can be avoided by rebinding at the beginning of the function: `let mut b = b;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can only mutate variables in a mutable binding, `fn name(a: i32)` creates an immutable binding for `a`, `mut a` is how we make it mutable to allow mutation. The same thing is true for a let binding: `let a = 99;` creates an immutable one, to make it mutable we use `let mut a = 99;`

Comment: ok so that makes sense. My assumption was that as i32 implements copy it would simply create a new, mutable instance of the i32 rather than requiring the arguments to be mutable.

Comment: Conceptually, it does create a new instance of i32. However unless the binding is declared as mutable, you can't change which instance is contained in the binding.